# How to allow users to print huge data in web application

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, printing

I am working on a Payroll Management System developed in Asp.Net MVC 4 Web application in which i am stuck at a point.

We need to allow Users to print salary slips of around 1000 employees.

Here is what i did,
i generated plain HTML of salary slip on a web page and called javascript function "window.print()" to print the web page. It worked perfectly for single salary slip.

Now when i tried it for salary slips of around 500 to 1000 employees, Page takes too much time to load or crashes.

Is there any other way to print huge data in web application? I also thought to generate PDF file which has salary slips of all employees and give it to user to download.

Comment: Do the printing server-side.

Comment: I would go for the pdf file solution. My suggestion is to generate the huge pdf on the server and allow downloading.

Comment: second option is much better

Comment: And Maybe if the HTML was improved it would not be such a problem. My guess is it is way more complicated than it needs to be.